# how to switch out music file for another using php echo

Tags: audio

this is the current code and audio. I would like to change for a different song, how do I do that?

```php
<source src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/thousandyears-fade.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
    <!--<source src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/thousandyears.ogg" type="audio/ogg">-->
```

Comment: Sorry, which part are you unsure about? You should be able to just change the filenames.

Answer (score -1):

you can't change file name. If you want to change file name dynamically try using acf for that.

https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/page-link/

Comment: OK, if I cannot change the name, there is now way to change the audio file for a different song using code? What code would I use for Harry Styles' adore you for example?